# Error 1-dimensional array given

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg 


A = np.array([[1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
              [0, -1,  0,  1, -1,  0],
              [0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1],
              [0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -1],
              [0, 10,-10,  0,-15, -5],
              [5,-10,  0,-20,  0,  0]])

B = np.array([[0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [200]])

a=np.array([[float(z) for z in x.split()] for x in input("Ingrese las filas separados por ; y las columnas por espacios: ").split(";")])

b = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(' ')
a = a.flatten()

print('solución de X: ')


print(np.linalg.solve(A,B))
print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
```

Buenas tengo este codigo y he intentado solucionar este error numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional, pero no he tenido la suerte de encontrar la solucion. Ademas es que no entiendo porque es "1 dimentional" si le estoy pasando los 2 parametros. Alguien me podria iluminar?

Para probar el funcionamiento pueden en el input de "a" meter los datos de A y en el de "b" los de B

Aca dejo el de a: 1 1 1 0 0 0 ; 0 -1 0 1 -1 0 ; 0 0 -1 0 0 1 ; 0 0 0 0 1 -1 ; 0 10 -10 0 -15 -5 ; 5 -10 0 -20 0 0

El de b: 0 0 0 0 0 200

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y donde haces la conversion de dato de la variable `b`?

Comment: solo haz `b = [float(y) for y in b]` despues de obtener los valores de `b`

Comment: xP   flatten() devuelve un array de una dimensión : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: @AnkiJedi gracias, me habia olvidado de eso (comente la linea >_<)

Comment: @Christian el código te funciona? porque B debería ser lineal, tal vez a este le quiso pasar el flatten?

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos. Si hacen la respuesta correcta, les marcare como respuesta correcta

Comment: @AnkiJedi si me funciona :/

Comment: weird, pero si da el resultado esperado entonces todo bien jajaja

Comment: @AnkiJedi hago la respuesta? o lo haces tu?

Comment: dale bro tu eres experto con los detalles en python xP

Comment: jeje, ok ahora la hago :D

Comment: Por si les quedo la duda, quite el flatten e hice el b = [float(y) for y in b] Por lo que fue gracias a ambos :)

Comment: @Galahad Igual añadí la respuesta, espero que entiendas el por que del error y no solo comentes o quites la linea por que asi el programa funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno como dijo @AnkiJedi tu error principal por el que se genera tu error es por esta linea `a = a.flatten()` pues el metodo `flatten()` regresa una copia de la matriz pero en forma de una sola dimensión y esto lo dice la propia [documentación](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html). Pero una cosa interesante es que al utilizar `np.linalg.solve(A,B))` es que el metodo `solve()` opera con matrices de dos dimensiones por lo que al utilizar `flatten()` en cualquier valor te dará el mismo error, por lo que es mejor quitarlo si tu plan es utilizar `solve()` para operar.

Otro error es que no estas convirtiendo los valores que obtienes en `b = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(' ')` se quedan como una lista de strings mas no son numero y no podrás operar con estos. Ahora si vamos con el código mejorado, el cual es poco.

```py
...

a=np.array([[float(z) for z in x.split()] for x in input("Ingrese las filas separados por ; y las columnas por espacios: ").split(";")])

b = input("Ingrese los valores del array x: ").split(' ')
b = [float(y) for y in b] #convertimos los valores

# a = a.flatten() esto no sirve en este caso

print('solución de X: ')

#imprimimos las soluciones
print(np.linalg.solve(A,B))
print(np.linalg.solve(a,b))
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias :)).
Y gracias por poner la razon, pues es claro que no tenia claro que hacian ciertas funciones, como este caso el flatten().